# How can I remove poison from a stack of weapons?

Tags: nethack

I've collected a large mixture of shuriken through polypiling. The different enchantments and BUCs are easy enough to mitigate for stacking, but I have quite a few that are poisoned (of differing ench/BUC). None are rustproof yet (that's one reason I want to stack). Besides using and waiting for it to wear away, dipping/rusting, or poisoning all of them, how can poison be removed?  Will Cancellation work?

Comment: I have tested: cancellation does not work. Still testing other ideas, I'll answer if I find something. Neither do potions of water FWIW (don't think they rust items)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind spending a healing potion on the project,  you can `#dip` the missiles into one.  [Common](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Potion_of_healing), [Extra](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Potion_of_extra_healing), and [Full](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Potion_of_full_healing) strength versions will all do the job.